# Geometric meaning of $\operatorname{Spec} \Bbb Z$ being final in the category of schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Is there a geometric meaning to $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{Z}$ being a final object in the category of schemes, or more generally $\operatorname{Spec} S$ in the category of $S$-schemes?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! I've made a slight upgrade to the typesetting of your post - \operatorname{Spec} produces the correct formatting and spacing for $\operatorname{Spec}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X$ is a variety defined over $\mathbb Z$, then there is a notion of its reduction $\operatorname{mod} p$. If $X$ is presented by explicit equations in some (affine or) projective space $\mathbb P_{\mathbb Z}^n$, then $X_p$ is the variety in $\mathbb P_{\mathbb F_p}^n$ presented by reducing the coefficients of the defining equations $\operatorname{mod} p$. If you unwind definitions, $X_p$ is the fiber of the natural map $X \to \operatorname{Spec} \mathbb Z$ over the point/prime ideal $(p) = p\mathbb Z$. So you could think of $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb Z$ as the parameter space for the reductions $\operatorname{mod} p$ of varieties or schemes defined over $\mathbb Z$ (although assuming that the varieties or schemes are flat over $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb Z$ will probably make this interpretation more reasonble).